# Converting response to arraybuffer

Tags: javascript, rest, axios

I am trying to convert a response to arraybuffer with axios. I keep getting an error message: "TypeError: response.arrayBuffer is not a function". Below is the code I wrote and suggestion on what I am doing wrong or a solution to this error.

```
 axios
      .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/file-api", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'http://localhost:8080',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true', 
          'Authorization': `bearer ${token}`
          
        },
      })
      .then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
      .then((res) => {
        const arrayBuffer = res.arrayBuffer();
        const objUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([arrayBuffer]));
        return objUrl;

        

        
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Comment: you seem to be using `axios` like it were `fetch` - you'd need `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` in the options you pass to axios.post if you want axios to return an arrayBuffer ... also you also seem to have a CORS issue and think sending CORS **response** headers in the **request** will bypass CORS ... it does not ... CORS is 100% controlled by the **server** - [learn CORS in 6 minuntes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNtFSVU-YTI) is a decent video if reading [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) isn't your thing

Comment: Yes you are right about the CORS response issue. For now everything is running on a local server so I intend to fully resolve that when moving to production. I will try the fetch and see the result.  Thanks for link of the video. I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: or you could still use `axios` but use it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading this post  [Axios vs. fetch(): Which is best for making HTTP requests?][1],

[1]: [https://blog.logrocket.com/axios-vs-fetch-best-http-requests/#:~:text=Axios%20automatically%20transforms%20the%20data,info%20on%20what%20the%20response](https://blog.logrocket.com/axios-vs-fetch-best-http-requests/#:%7E:text=Axios%20automatically%20transforms%20the%20data,info%20on%20what%20the%20response). and then the comment by @Bravo,
I notice using axios may not be able to provide an arraybuffer as a responseType.
In the case of arraybuffer, it is best to use fetch.